# Show video and buttons on same screen in Android

Tags: android, layout, view, imagebutton, android-videoview

I am trying to create a view that has a video playing and two ImageButtons all on the same screen. I am using VideoView to contain my video and ImageButtons for both of my buttons. Both display correctly when I test each feature independently, but they will not display together at the same time when I try to show both on the same screen! I have tried a number of layouts (frame, linear, relative), constraining the VideoView to a smaller layout_width & layout_height, and have tried weights in the xml file, but nothing seems to be working. Displaying this seems too straightforward to require a custom View, but I will do it if I have to.

Here are my questions: do you know how to make imageButtons and VideoView display on the same screen?
Can you use Android views like VideoView and ImageButton when you create a custom view? Or can you just draw 2D things on canvases in custom views?

Here is my code as reference: XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/videopart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     <VideoView
         android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
         android:layout_width="395dp"
         android:layout_height="111dp" >
       </VideoView>
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">   

        <ImageButton
             android:contentDescription="@string/top"
             android:id="@+id/topbutton"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
             android:paddingRight="5dip" 
             android:src="@drawable/yesbutton"
             android:background="@null"/>  
       <ImageButton
             android:contentDescription="@string/bottom"
             android:id="@+id/bottombutton"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
             android:paddingLeft="5dip" 
             android:src="@drawable/nobutton"
             android:background="@null">
        </ImageButton>           

    </LinearLayout>
```

And activity:

```
public class iplayer extends Activity {
VideoView videoHolder;
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton top, bottom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    videoHolder = new VideoView(this);

    //if you want the controls to appear
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.interactivevid); 
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

    // video finish listener:
    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // The video has finished, return from this activity
            finish(); //close activity
        }
    });

    videoHolder.requestFocus();
    /*
    videoHolder.requestLayout();
    videoHolder.invalidate();
    videoHolder.getLayoutParams().width = 20;//480;     
     */
    //start video
    drawButtons();
    //videoHolder.setPadding(BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND, BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND, BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND, BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND);
    videoHolder.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 200);
    setContentView(videoHolder); // used to actually put in video. when removed, shows buttons 
    videoHolder.start();    

 }


private void drawButtons(){

    //make buttons invisible
    top = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.topbutton);
    top.setImageResource(R.drawable.yesbutton);
    top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    bottom = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bottombutton);
    bottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.nobutton); 
    bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: It has something to do with setContentView(videoholder), which makes the video take up the whole screen. Instead, the buttons and the video should be passed into the contentView somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not by a computer where I can test this now but what you may want to try is an absolute layout.

You should be able to position the buttons on top of the video with it here is an example
https://web.archive.org/web/20200927175004/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/absolutelayout-in-android-xml.html

You may also want to try putting the buttons and the VideoView in the same layout

Comment: Thanks pegisys. Absolute layout didn't work either though. I tried putting the buttons and video view in the same layout with absolute and other layouts.. still no success.